# Python syntax error on while loop while generating a random number

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I am programming in python. I'm trying to have the user guess a number between 1 and 100. I'm sure I have the correct code, but I keep getting a syntax error around 'while'

```
import random

def guessthenumber():
    print("Welcome user. In this game, you must correctly guess a randomly generated number between 1 and 100.")  

    guessamount = 1
    randomnumber = random.randrange(1, 100)

    numberguess = int(input("Please enter your guess")

    while numberguess != numbertoguess:
        if numberguess < numbertoguess:
            print("You must guess higher.")
        elif numberguess > numbertoguess:
            print("You must guess lower.")
        guessamount += 1
    print("You have correctly guessed the number! It took you {} guesses".format(guessamount))
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Youre missing a ) at the end of the line where you ask for input

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a parenthesis:

```
numberguess = int(input("Please enter your guess"))
```

Answer (score 0):

numberguess = int(input("Please enter your guess")

you miss a ) at the end to close the int() part ...

Comment: I was changing a few things. Just deleted a thing that said numbertoguess = int(randomnumber). I'll change it back. Anyway, thansk guys!

Comment: you are very welcome... if you ever need help with python I will try to help you again :)